# Rails 4 Dynamic Collection_Select

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, collection-select

This seems to be a pretty popular question here, though I have yet to find a tutorial or thread that works for me. I have a two dropdown menus in a form, Team Type and User Role, where User Role is dependent on Team Type. The options for Team Type are stored in the model as an array, since there are only 5 choices (Artist, Venue, Promoter, Independent, Other). What I would like to do is source the selections for User Role from the model as well, with the proper array selected depending on the Team Type. Is this possible, or do I need to create models for each Team Type and pass an ID to a join table to select the proper User Role? Thank you.

**Model**

```
class WaitingList < ActiveRecord::Base
  COMPANIES = ['—Select—', 'Artist Team', 'Venue Team', 'Promoter', 'Independent', 'Other']
  ARTIST_TEAM = ['-Select-', 'Artist', 'Manager', 'Tour Manager', 'Production Manager', 'Agent', 'Other']
  VENUE_TEAM = ['-Select-', 'Artist Liason', 'Stage Manager', 'Production Manager', 'Owner', 'Other']
  PROMOTER = ['-Select', 'Talent Buyer', 'Other']
  INDEPENDENT = ['-Select', 'Agent', 'Photo/Video', 'Tour Manager', 'Manager', 'Other']
end
```

**Form**

```
<div class="form--col">
  <label>Team Type</label>
    <div class="dropdown-wrapper">
      <%= f.collection_select :company_type, WaitingList::COMPANIES, :to_s, :to_s, {:include_blank => false}, {:class => "form--dropdown -team_type"} %>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form--col -inactive">
  <label>Main Role</label>
    <div class="dropdown-wrapper">
      <%= f.collection_select :user_type, WaitingList::USERS, :to_s, :to_s, {:include_blank => false}, {:class => "form--dropdown", :disabled => "disabled"} %>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should do it ajax request by adding javascript `onChange` function. Also add a new method to handle this ajax request

**Form**

```
<div class="form--col">
  <label>Team Type</label>
  <div class="dropdown-wrapper">
    <%= f.collection_select :company_type, WaitingList::COMPANIES, :to_s, :to_s, {include_blank: false}, {onchange: "getRoles();", class: "form--dropdown -team_type"} %>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form--col -inactive">
  <label>Main Role</label>
  <div class="dropdown-wrapper">
    <%= f.collection_select :user_type, {}, {prompt: 'Main Role'} {:class => "form--dropdown", :disabled => "disabled"} %>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript file**

```
function getRoles() {
  var currentRole = $('#company_type :selected').val(); 
  $.ajax({
     url: '/waiting_lists/'+ currentRole +'/get_role',
     dataType: "json",
     success: function(data) {
       $('#user_type').html('');
       for (i in roles) {
         if (roles[i] != undefined) {
           $('#user_type').append("<option value=\""+roles[i]+"\">"+roles[i]+"</option>");
         }  
       }
     } 
  });      
}
```

**Controller**

I added a route for waiting_lists controller

```
  def get_role()
    if params[:role]
      case params[:role]
      when 'Artist Team'  
        roles = WaitingList::ARTIST_TEAM
      when 'Venue Team'
        roles = WaitingList::VENUE_TEAM
      when 'Promoter'
        roles = WaitingList::PROMOTER
      when 'Independent'
        roles = WaitingList::INDEPENDENT
      when 'Others'
        roles = []
      end      
      render json: {roles: roles}
    end 
  end
```

**Routes**

Added route for waiting_lists controller

```
resources(:waiting_lists) do
  collection do
    get(':role/get_role', action: :get_role)
  end
end
```

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for. I am getting an error in the first line of the JS function - "Parsing Error - Unexpected token getRoles", any idea what that stems from?

Comment: Had to add var roles = data.roles; but it works perfectly now, thank you!